# Need help with building C# example in ANTLR 2.7

Tags: java, nant, antlr

I need to build the CSHARP V1 example which comes with ANTLR v 2.7.7.

Command: 
D:\Comp\antlr\examples\csharp\csharp_v1>nant

I am getting the following output:

D:\Comp\antlr\examples\csharp\csharp_v1>D:\Comp\nant\bin\nant
NAnt 0.85 (Build 0.85.2478.0; release; 10/14/2006)
Copyright (C) 2001-2006 Gerry Shaw
http://nant.sourceforge.net

Buildfile: file:///D:/Comp/antlr/examples/csharp/csharp_v1/csharp_v1.build
Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0
Target(s) specified: test

[tstamp] Monday, May 11, 2009 11:21:20 PM.
     [echo] Building project: 'CSharp v1 Grammar Sample for ANTLR' generate:
     [exec] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/Tool
     [exec] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.Tool
     [exec]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
     [exec]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [exec]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
     [exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     [exec]  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     [exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     [exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
     [exec] Could not find the main class: antlr.Tool.  Program will exit.
     [exec] Exception in thread "main"

BUILD FAILED - 0 non-fatal error(s), 11 warning(s)

D:\Comp\antlr\examples\csharp\csharp_v1\csharp_v1.build(52,10):
External Program Failed: java.exe (return code was 1)

Total time: 0.2 seconds.

I have nANT working properly for other builds.

I am not a java guy...any help would be helpful.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the make file csharp_v1.build.

On line 10 change it from:

`<property name="antlr.dir" value="..\..\.."/>`

to

`<property name="antlr.dir" value="..\..\..\antlr.jar"/>`